# Replace placeholder attribute using JQuery unicode

Tags: jquery

I can't get a magnifying glass to appear in my placeholder. I have it in a function so when I click a button the placeholder text will be changed to `"search our catalog"` but I keep getting `"ὐE search...."` with the following code:

```
$("#search-box").attr("placeholder", "\u1F50E search our catalog");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're transporting your HTML as UTF-8 (as you should), you can directly insert the Unicode glyph:

```js
$("#search-box").attr("placeholder", " search our catalog");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="search-box">
```

Answer (score 0):

> but I keep getting "ὐE search...."

That’s because you are using the `\u` escape syntax wrong. `\u` is only valid with *four* hexadecimal digits. (And that’s why you got `ὐ`, which is `\u1F50`, followed by an `E` …)

However, you can use the UTF-16 representation of the character, `D8 3D DD 0E`, by splitting it into *two* `\uXXXX` parts:

```
$("#search-box").attr("placeholder", "\uD83D\uDD0E search our catalog");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8tuhfthL/